# Convert Postman "get new authorization token" to curl command

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, postman, export

I'm trying to generate/export CURL code from Postman. This works very well with single GET request with basic authentication. I can build the command in Postman (nice UI) and generate/export code in many formats including CURL.

https://blog.postman.com/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/

Now with Dynamics Business Central software, I need get access token first (oAuth 2.0) and then get the actual data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-connect-apps#AAD

All works fine in Postman, but...

1. Get oAuth token --> How to get/export CURL code for this?
2. Get actual data

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To see what is going throught postman, you can go to

View -> Show Postman Console.

Tip. Clear the console log and then click "Get New Access Token" and you will see the only console as what you need.

Comment: This is very helpful. Do you know if it is possible to extract a cURL command from the console logs?

Comment: As far as I know you can only generate cURL from a new request. The Postman console just show the bytes throughout request/response streaming.